# why returning JSONResult from overridden Json method doesn't work and ContentResult works?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jsonresult

Recently I discovered a weird scenario while trying to override Json method of Controller class so that I could use JSON.net contract resolver. It works perfectly if at the end I return an object of ContentResult and upcast it to ActionResult. However it doesn't work if I try to return object of JSONResult.

```
protected new ContentResult Json(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behaviour = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet)
    {
        var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        if (Request.RequestType == WebRequestMethods.Http.Get && behaviour == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("GET is not permitted for this request");
        }

        var jsonResult = new ContentResult
        {
            Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, jsonSerializerSettings),
            ContentType = "application/json",
        };

        return jsonResult;
    }
```

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Answer (score 1):

Your overrided `Json` method should return `JsonResult`.

You're able to do it with `ContentResult` becouse they both inherit from `ActionResult` class.

If you want this working in any case - you could return `ActionResult` from your override. But there is another problem - all your controller methods that will use this method should also return `ActionResult`.

It could be not a big problem but if you want to keep your code clean you should implement your logic as `ActionFilterAttribute` and register it in `FilterConfig` for global usage.

Comment: I understand why it works with ContentResult but I totally don't get why it doesn't work when I am using JsonResult. When I return JsonResult object this is what I get.                                                                                " This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet".                          This is something that we get when trying to call default Json method without specifiying AllowGet.

Comment: @HemAcharya so what do you want? allowGet always?

Comment: I am not wanting allowGet always. But even if I explicitly pass JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet while I am returning JSONResult object from overridden method, I get the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior(v=vs.118).aspx) while using JsonResult as return type?

Comment: yes. I use  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet. But even on doing that if I return object of JSON result from overloaded method, it basically throws same error if I would normally call a Json method (without overloading) without passing AllowGet.